# database design for many questions with different answer datatypes

Tags: database, database-design

I have a problem with my database design.
I have two options in mind but none of them really solves my problem:

Option 1:

```
FB (ID, Year, Question, Value)  
    1 | 2004| Q1      | hello  
    1 | 2004| Q2500   | 15.2.12  
    1 | 2004| Q2      | 56€  
    1 | 2003| Q1      | bye  
    2 | 2003| Q2      | 55€
```

The problem with Option 1 is that the data type of field “Value” can be really everything! To solve that problem I thought of

1. creating a table for each datatype or
2. changing the table to FB (ID, Year, Question, Valueint, Valuestring,….etc.)

Neither 1. nor 2. seems right to me.

Option 2:

```
   FB (ID, Year,   Q1,    Q2,   ….,   Q2500)   
    1| 2004 | hello| 56€ |,....,| 15.2.12  
    1| 2003 | bye  | …...|,….., |…..  
    2| 2003 | salut| 55€ |, …..,|…..
```

The number of Questions (Q1-QX ) may vary a lot.

Any suggestions are appreciated! Thanks...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for

```
CREATE TABLE Questions (
   QuestionID varchar(5) not null primary key,
   AnswerType varchar(10) not null,
   constraint CK_Question_Types CHECK (AnswerType in ('INT','CHAR','BOOL')), --Add more appropriate type names
   constraint UQ_Questions_TypeCheck UNIQUE (QuestionID,AnswerType)
)
```

and:

```
CREATE TABLE Answers (
    ID int not null,
    Year int not null,
    QuestionID varchar(5) not null,
    AnswerType varchar(10) not null,
    IntAnswer int null,
    CharAnswer varchar(max) null,
    BoolAnswer bit null,
    constraint FK_Answers_Questions FOREIGN KEY (QuestionID) references Questions,
    constraint FK_Answers_Question_TypeCheck FOREIGN KEY (QuestionID,AnswerType) references Questions (QuestionID,AnswerType),
    constraint CK_Answer_Types CHECK (
       (IntAnswer is null or AnswerType='INT') and
       (CharAnswer is null or AnswerType='CHAR') and
       (BoolAnswer is null or AnswerType='BOOL') and
       (IntAnswer is not null or CharAnswer is not null or BoolAnswer is not null)
    )
 )
```

This lets you ensure that each answer is of the correct type, and not null, whilst ensuring no extraneous data ends up in the table.

---

The use of two foreign keys isn't *really* required (you could remove `FK_Answers_Questions`), but I prefer to document that the real FK reference is on `QuestionID`, whilst we want to enforce a constraint across the tables, using the second one and the new `CHECK` constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I would create two tables:

```
Create Table tblQuestions (
     ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     Year varchar(4) Default '',
     QuestionText varchar(4000) Default '',
     AnswerDataType varchar(50) Default '' )

Create Table tblAnswers (
     ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     tblQuestions_ID int Default 0,
     Answer varchar(255) Default '' )
```

Then I would create a function or sproc to validate that an answer was given in the correct data type and return TRUE or FALSE.  Unfortunately I don't have time to write that code.